# how to identify an objects place within an array

Tags: arrays, angularjs, object, select, dropdownbox

I load an array of objects into a select box.  The user makes a selection... how can identify which array object they chose so I can use it in downstream work?

For example if user chooses the 2nd object in the array... how can identify the selection was the second item in the array?

http://jsfiddle.net/silvajeff/LRXkV/3/

```
angular.module('demoApp', []).controller('DemoController', function ($scope) {

$scope.captions = [{
    name: 'A',
    value: 'a'
}, {
    name: 'B',
    value: 'b'
}, {
    name: 'C',
    value: 'c'
}, {
    name: 'D',
    value: 'd'
}, {
    name: 'E',
    value: 'e'
}];

//how could I determine that 3 should be the number used in the expression below
$scope.selectedCaption = $scope.captions[3];
});
```

Comment: why dont you simply pass the caption object the user clicked on? Otherwise you would have to search through the array or use the `$index` property of `ng-repeat`

Comment: Unfortunately in my scenario the caption is not useful for what I ultimately need to do.  This is a simplification of the problem, but I was just wondering if there was anyway for angular or javascript to get the object number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wotch for index of selected item in array:

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
    return $scope.captions.indexOf($scope.selectedCaption);
  },
  function(newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal != oldVal) {
      alert('New index of selected caption :' + newVal);
    }
  });
```

Or just watch for `selectedCaption` anf get index in listener function:

```
$scope.$watch('selectedCaption',
function (newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal != oldVal) {
        alert('New index of selected caption :' + $scope.captions.indexOf(newVal));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code was in the body's `onload` so the module wasn't even properly initialized, that's why your fiddle wasn't working.

`$scope.selectedCaption` is the select's model and will be automatically updated as the select value changes.

http://jsfiddle.net/LRXkV/2/

Comment: oops.  Here's the updated fiddle...  this still doesn't answer the question I need to find the object # in the array.  The reason for this has to do with me needing to reload that array and setting it's initial value to the previous selection. http://jsfiddle.net/silvajeff/LRXkV/3/